# MySQL convert DMS coordinates to Decimal Degrees

Tags: mysql, coordinates

I have approx. 70,000 rows of coordinates in Degrees Minutes Seconds format that I need to convert to Decimal Degrees format ([screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1pU3.jpg)). I'm fairly new to MySQL and am stuck on how to write a function that will batch convert them. I'd like the converted coordinates to populate another column, decLatitude or decLongitude.

Another thread ([MySQL convert Degree, Minutes, Seconds to Degree decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868228/mysql-convert-degree-minutes-seconds-to-degree-decimal)) asks the same question but the answers provided there did not help me. One response showed a reverse solution (degree to DMS) but I couldn't figure out how to modify it for my purposes. Any help with writing this function would be greatly appreciated!